# Angular ngIf+else with style

Tags: angular, styles, margin, angular-ng-if

This is what I want to do

```
If value(depth) = 1 --> margin-left:10px
else value(depth) = 2 --> margin-left:20px
else value(depth) = 3 --> margin-left:30px
```

ex) value * 10px

I wrote the following code myself but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="comment" *ngIf="comment.depth === 1" style="margin-left:10px">
<div class="comment" *ngIf="comment.depth === 2" style="margin-left:20px">
<div class="comment" *ngIf="comment.depth === 3" style="margin-left:30px">
```

How should I change the code to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use style that dependent of the current depth value.
here is an example to get the idea:

**HTML**

```
<div class="comment" [style.marginLeft.px]="getDepth(comment.depth)">
```

**TS**

```
getDepth = (depth) => {
 return depth*10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!